# Bind multiple parameters match against fulltext search

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm implementing a search feature based on tags, and I have the following SQL to match keywords in a `tags` column in one of my tables.

Example:

```
row 1 tags column:   car city night
row 2 tags column:   truck city day
```

SQL:

```
WHERE MATCH(s.tags) AGAINST (+:keyword IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

However if the user searches multiple keywords separated by spaces, such as "car city ...", the query should be:

```
WHERE MATCH(s.tags) AGAINST ('+:keyword1 +:keyword2 +...' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Currently I have just

`$stmt->bindParam(":keyword", $keyword);`

which won't produce what I want, I believe it produces:

```
WHERE MATCH(s.tags) AGAINST (+'keyword1 keyword2 ...' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

How would I bind each keyword separately to produce that when there an unknown number of keywords? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I was able to solve it.

Use a single placeholder:

```
WHERE MATCH(s.tags) AGAINST (:keyword IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Split the keyword into an array of words separated by spaces:

```
$keywords = preg_split('/\s+/', $keyword);
$numKeywords = count($keywords);
```

Then when binding the parameter, concatenate each keyword with a plus:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numKeywords; $i++){
  $keywordBind .= "+".$keywords[$i]." ";
}
$stmt->bindParam(":keyword", $keywordBind);
```